# launching a method from parent window context?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

The system begins with a main page, where a main table and sub table are visible. Then when the user clicks the ReceiveOrder button, a new WPF window is created through the an Icommand which executes the following method

```
private void ReceiveOrder(object sender)
{
    ReceiveOrderDialogWindow dialog = new ReceiveOrderDialogWindow()
    {
        Topmost = true
    };
    dialog.ShowDialog();

}
```

ReceiveOrderDialogWindow has it's context set to a copy of the main page.

```
public ReceiveOrderDialogWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new OrdersViewModel("Orders");
    this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
}
```

Within ReceiveOrderDialogWindow. When the user clicks confirm, another ICommand is triggered in OrdersViewModel.

```
private void ReceiveOrderConfirm(object sender)                                                                                                  
{
    createReceipt(sender);
    requestSerials(sender);
    Db.UpdateTable(SubVwr.Tables[0].UpdateTableQuery, SubVwr.Tables[0].Tbl);

}
```

---

If I run createReceipt() inside of RecieveOrder it works perefctly, however when I try and run it inside of ReceiveOrderConfirm() it returns that the main table is null. I understand that this is because the context has changed into a different instance of the OrdersViewModel, one where the main table doesn't exist. Does anyone know a way to execute a method from a parent window's context?

Comment: Why are you using two different instances instead of injecting ReceiveOrderDialogWindow with the already existing instance?

Comment: Just did that now. I'll update with an answer if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know a way to execute a method from a parent window's context?

Well, you would first need to get a reference to the parent window then. A better approach would probably be to inject the `ReceiveOrderDialogWindow` with the already existing instance of the `OrdersViewModel` and operate on this one only:

**ReceiveOrder:**

```
private void ReceiveOrder(object sender)
{
    ReceiveOrderDialogWindow dialog = new ReceiveOrderDialogWindow(this.DataContext as OrdersViewModel)
    {
        Topmost = true
    };
    dialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

**ReceiveOrderDialogWindow:**

```
public ReceiveOrderDialogWindow(OrdersViewModel viewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = viewModel;
    this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
}
```